# jquery launch checkbox check not working as expected

Tags: jquery, events, checkbox

I've got this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $("input[type='checkbox']").click();

        $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(e) { 

            if ( $("input[type='checkbox']").is(":checked") === true ) 
            {
                $("textarea").val("");
                $("textarea").prop("placeholder", "");  
                $("textarea").prop("disabled", true);
            }
            else
            {
                $("textarea").prop("disabled", false);
                $("textarea").prop("placeholder", "Write here"); 
            }

        }); //checkbox .change()

    });
```

When the page is loaded the click event happens but the change event is not launched.

Is that correct? Or am I doing something wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: you're calling click() before altering the change event.

Comment: call `.change()` not `.click()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the event after clicking the checkbox. And also you should use "this" inside the event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {



    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(e) { 

        if ( $(this).is(":checked") === true ) 
        {
            $("textarea").val("");
            $("textarea").prop("placeholder", "");  
            $("textarea").prop("disabled", true);
        }
        else
        {
            $("textarea").prop("disabled", false);
            $("textarea").prop("placeholder", "Write here"); 
        }

    }); //checkbox .change()

    $("input[type='checkbox']").click();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing :

```
 if ( $("input[type='checkbox']").is(":checked") === true )
```

to

```
if (this.checked )
```

Answer (score 0):

At the time of click you have not attached the event. Write your `$("input[type='checkbox']").click();` after writing the event definition. Try same code as

```
$(document).ready(function() {        

    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(e) { 
        alert("Yes event triggered now");
        if ( $(this).is(":checked") === true ) 
        {
            $("textarea").val("");
            $("textarea").prop("placeholder", "");  
            $("textarea").prop("disabled", true);
        }
        else
        {
            $("textarea").prop("disabled", false);
            $("textarea").prop("placeholder", "Write here"); 
        }

    }); //checkbox .change()

$("input[type='checkbox']").click();
});
```